# consumir api rest com react e renderizar os dados em uma tabela

Tags: node.js, api, react

meu codigo:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

import PageHeader from '../template/pageHeader'
import cadastroForm from './cadastroForm'
import cadastroList from './cadastroList'

const URL = 'http://localhost:3003/api/cadastros'

export default class Cadastro extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { listaItens: [] }
        this.refresh()

   }

    refresh(Nome = '') {
        const search = Nome ? `&Nome__regex=/${Nome}/` : ''
        axios.get(`${URL}?sort=-createdAt${search}`)
        .then(response => { this.setState({ listaItens: response.data}); })
        .catch(() => { console.log('Erro ao recuperar os dados'); });    
    }

     render() {
       return (

     <div>

     {this.state.listaItens.map(function(item)  {console.log(item)})}

      </div>
        ) 
    }


}
```

retorna:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando você precisa consumir dados de uma API é recomendado você fazer a requisição no método [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount), que é um dos métodos do ciclo de vida de um componente React. Além disso, você [não deve chamar o método setState() no construtor](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor) (e no método refresh você chama esse método). Assim, a primeira alteração necessária no seu código é invocar o método refresh() dentro componentDidMount().

Depois disso, para renderizar os dados que você carregou na tabela basta fazer um loop no array listaItens e retornar os itens dentro de uma estrutura de tabela.

O seu código vai ficar da seguinte forma depois das alterações:

```
export default class Cadastro extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { listaItens: [] }

    this.refresh = this.refresh.bind(this);
}

refresh(Nome = '') {
    const search = Nome ? `&Nome__regex=/${Nome}/` : ''
    axios.get(`${URL}?sort=-createdAt${search}`)
    .then(response => { this.setState({ listaItens: response.data}); })
    .catch(() => { console.log('Erro ao recuperar os dados'); });    
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.refresh()
}

render() {
    return (

        <div>
            <table>

                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Nome</th>
                    <th scope="col">CPF/CNPJ</th>
                </tr>

               {this.state.listaItens.map(function(item)  
                  {
                     return (
                         <tr>
                             <td>{item.Nome}</td>
                             <td>{item.CpfCnpj}</td>
                         </tr>
                     )
                  }
               }

            </table>
        </div>
    ) 
}
```